# WinRT - Printing an App

Tags: printing, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

How do we get that an RT application is register with Print

```
PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
```

This will directy init the Printing Charm but i need to check whether the app is register with Print.

Any Idea?

```
    protected void RegisterForPrinting()
    {
        PrintManager printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
        if(printMan == null)
            return;
        // Create the PrintDocument.
        printDocument = new PrintDocument();

        // Save the DocumentSource.
        printDocumentSource = printDocument.DocumentSource;

        // Add an event handler which creates preview pages.
        printDocument.Paginate += CreatePrintPreviewPages;

        // Add an event handler which provides a specified preview page.
        printDocument.GetPreviewPage += GetPrintPreviewPage;

        // Add an event handler which provides all final print pages.
        printDocument.AddPages += AddPrintPages;

        // Create a PrintManager and add a handler for printing initialization.

        printMan.PrintTaskRequested += PrintTaskRequested;

        // Initialize print content for this scenario
        //PreparePrintContent();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "register with Print"? What are you trying to check for?

Comment: Wring up the print events.. with above code...

Comment: This code is from the MS Example Gallery? It's a complete example, so I currently do know, what exactly you want